# "For all X, X =A iff X=B, therefore the A = B". Is this logically correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, logic

Suppose I want to prove ( in elementary arithmetics, or, maybe, in an abstract additive group)  that :

the additive inverse of (a+b) = -b + -a

May I proceed as follows?

Suppose X = - ( a+b).

Now, X = - (a+b)

iff  (a+b) + X =O

iff  -a+ (a+b) +X =-a+O

iff  (-a+a) +b +X = -a

iff   0  + b   + X = -a

iff      b + X     = -a

iff    -b + (b + X)  = -b + -a

iff    (-b+b) + X   = -b + -a

iff      0  + X    = -b + -a

iff          X     =  -b +-a

**Did I really prove that the additive inverse of (a+b) is (-b+-a)?**

**Or** did I only prove that

**for all X ( X is the additive inverse of (a+b) iff X = -b + -a).**

Is there a difference between these two results?

The problem ( for me ) is that **the desired statement is a categorical one, while the result I actually obtain seems to be an hypothetical one** ( a conditional statement).

Other example.

I want to prove that log base b of b^n is n

I set X = log base b of b^n and I say

X = log base b of b^n

iff b^X = b^n

iff X = n

Did I really prove that  log base b of b^n = n ,

or did I only prove that

for all X (  X = log base b of b^n iff X =n) ?

Comment: It would be better if you mention textbooks you have read. Answers and its details depend on what you have read.

Comment: @Hanul Jeon.- This is a question I asked myself while trying to prove just for fun some basic abstract algebra laws, in particular : " the inverse of the product a.b is the product of the inverse of b and of the inverse of a". I realized that my little personal proof required the logical validity of the principle mentioned. If I'm correct this principle is used in some  algebra books to prove logarithm properties.

Comment: What about applying "for all X ( X is the additive inverse of (a+b) iff X = -b + -a)" to $X=-b+(-a)$? In that case, we have "$-b+(-a)$ is the additive inverse of $(a+b)$ iff $-b+(-a)=-b+(-a)$. Since the RHS is obviously true, the LHS is also true: $-b+(-a)$ is indeed the additive inverse of $(a+b)$.

Comment: @ Taladils. That looks perfect to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "For all X, X =A iff X=B, therefore the A = B". Is this logically correct?

Yes. If $X =A$ iff $X=B$ is true for all $X$, then it should also be true for $A$, and thus we get:

$A =A$ iff $A=B$

But *of course* $A=A$ is true: that's a tautology. So, between $A =A$ iff $A=B$ and $A=A$, we can conclude $A=B$

Comment: should have thought about this...

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames Isn't logic great? :)

Comment: The original statement is an instance of the Yoneda embedding being full and faithful which is itself a special case of the Yoneda lemma. (Alternatively, this can more directly be viewed as a special case of an enriched Yoneda lemma.) Namely, this is the case when the embedded category is discrete. The argument you give here is exactly (one direction of) the proof of the Yoneda lemma.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between your two statements. In fact, you can show that they are equivalent; more generally, you can see that $x=y$ if and only if $\forall z: z=x\leftrightarrow z=y$: Under $x=y$, we can observe that if $x=z$ then $y=z$ by transitivity and symmetricity of $=$. The remaining direction follows from taking $z=x$ in our assumption.

Moreover, the $x$ in your proof is specific, not arbitrary. That is, you just use the symbol $x$ to abbreviate $-a-b$. You may be satisfactory if you replace every $x$ to $(-a-b)$ in your proof.